# Request time out ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

Hello it my first time here hope I do it right.
So the problem is like this:
i have a VPS with IIS6,
when I try to open the site from my PC I get request timeout error.
but when I open the site from the server (127.0.0.1) it fine.
I can open some simple pages (simple asp.net code/ only html).
oh! and i tried to upload the server to a different host, and it wockrs fine in the different host
BTW the server is Microst Server 2008

Comment: It sounds like your VPS doesn't have the proper firewall security permissions opened up to allow incoming HTTP traffic. Where is your VPS running?

Comment: @DavidJeske i can run simple pages ~ but some pages block out from public.
VPS- is azure (microsft)

Comment: try an IIS/Azure forum, such as https://forums.asp.net/1247.aspx/1?Azure+and+ASP+NET